# ¿Graficar dia a dia y semanalmente?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen día, me encuentro con esta situación y me gustaría alguna idea de cómo solucionarla por favor, esto aunado a que soy nuevo programando en c#.
Necesito realizar una gráfica que me muestre la producción de 4 líneas (1,2,3,4) y los días de la semana (l,m,m,j,v,s,d), los datos ya están en el sistema,
pero cómo hacerlo "simple" para el usuario que pueda ver la producción de las líneas el dia jueves por ejemplo y cambiar al martes y así consecutivamente.
La idea que tengo es crear 7 tabControl para cada dia de la semana y un tab mas que contenga las 4 líneas y según la selección lo grafique, que opinan? a su vez tendrá que tomar la información y las capturas de las gráficas y generar excel...

De antemano gracias por su tiempo!!!